# Soap Error - Procedure 'loginParam not present'

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2

I'm getting a soap error, and I haven't been able to trace it.  It is blocking an integration and generally causing havoc.  Since it is happening immediately with login, I haven't been able to trace it further.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Procedure 'loginParam' not present
```

reflected similarly in the apache error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Procedure 'loginParam' not present in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 889
```

This occurs when trying to log in with a valid username/password (which work on the v1 API):

```
$api_url_v2 = "https://xxx/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1";
$cli = new SoapClient($api_url_v2);
$session_id = $cli->login($username, $password);
```

I've tried flushing my WSDL cache, as suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425909/magento-soap-2-api-fatal-error-procedure-login-not-present

I've also tried modifying my WSI-Compliance settings, to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Additional info:
I traced out the incoming client call, and see this... although it certainly doesn't look right to me, I've never been a SOAP guy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:loginParam/><param1>{SOME_PASSWORD}</param1></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The headers look like this:

```
{"Host":"some-server.com","Connection":"Keep-Alive","User-Agent":"PHP-SOAP\\/5.6.20","Content-Type":"text\\/xml; charset=utf-8","SOAPAction":"\\"\\"","Content-Length":"235"}
```

So... my username appears to have been lost, and I'm not even sure if it is calling the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your login call, you need to format the passed parameters as an array  -

```
$api_url_v2 = "https://xxx/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1";
$cli = new SoapClient($api_url_v2, array('trace' => 1));
$session_id = $cli->login(array('username' => $username, 'apiKey' => $password));
```

The `array('trace' => 1)` parameter on the SoapClient " enables tracing of request so faults can be backtraced. This defaults to FALSE" src: [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)

This could be useful while experimenting with a new api implementation.

Comment: Both formats should work, but I have tried the array version as well, with the same results on both the client and server.  The trace parameter isn't giving me anything different.  Worse, this isn't a new implementation... it suddenly stopped working yesterday, even though there have been no changes to the system.

Comment: Are you running this from a test script? You should definitely be seeing output from the trace. Also, as an end result do you want the api to be using WSI compliance?

Comment: Yeah, the code is just a test script to communicate with the server.  It works properly with the v1 API.  I've tried toggling the WSI compliance on and off, and both appear to be broken.

Comment: It looks like a v1 call, which won't work with v2. loginParam is actually a parameter for WSI compliant mode - if you don't have a need to use WSI compliance leave it off, it changes the format of basically everything.

Comment: Also, be sure you are clearing the cache after you make changes to the api settings, so that the wsdl is regenerated.

Comment: WSI compliance is actually set to off currently, and the WSDL cache (and, for good measure, the Magento cache) is cleared every time I make a change.  The behavior I document above with loginParam is still happening.

Comment: Right, but according to your server side trace you are sending the loginParam node, which won't be present unless WS-I compliance is on. With WS-I off, on v2, and with the correct wsdl in place the code in my original answer works every time. Omitting 'username' => and 'apiKey' => results in "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'username' property........" every time on v2. I would make sure you have WS-I off, a fresh v2 wsdl, and try the exact code in my original answer.

Comment: Bleh, my test code had an error.  Turning off WSI actually worked, but my test was invalid.  Thanks much.

Comment: Glad it helped! I went through a similar experience with a WS-I enabled site, foggy details, etc, and it was a complete pain!